# Use Java in ActionScript 3 - is it possible?

Tags: java, actionscript

I'm creating an MMO game. Client side is ActionScript 3 and server side is Java. I have to synchronize both languages. The big problem is the Timer class in ActionScript 3. When you used this class actually 1 second is not real time 1 second, depending on framerate and operation system and so on. Now I am looking for solution where is it possible to use Java Timer and TimerTask in ActionScript 3. I mean is it possible to integrate .jar file into AS3 project or any other solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even if it were possible, there's no reason why Java's Timer should be more accurate than ActionScript's Timer. It still doesn't give a real time guarantee.

Comment: It's certainly possible; you could write a Java parser in Actionscript and use it that way.  However, as Boann noted it wouldn't help with timing.  Why do you need to synchronize the two?  Simply polling the server on a regular basis from your as3 code should suffice to get environment updates to the client.